# Cannot connect to a on-premise VM via Cloud VPN from Google Cloud Run

Tags: networking, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn, google-cloud-run

I am trying to reach an on-premise machine (let's call it `exovie`) from Google Cloud Run via the Serverless VPC Connector.

### Simplified network configuration

This is how the network is configured:

1. The VPC is connected to our on-premise network `172.20.0.0/20` using a Google Cloud VPN `exoscale-at-vie-1-tunnel`.

[image: Cloud VPN]

2. My application `train-graphql` is deployed on Cloud Run (fully managed, europe-west6) and is attempting to access the `exovie` VM via a Serverless VPS Connector `euw6-connector` (also europe-west6, network: `10.94.0.0/28`).
3. Routes are published to a Cloud Router.

[image: Cloud Router]

4. I also have a `services`  subnetwork `10.172.10.0/24` used by some Google Cloud Compute Engine VMs which hosts a LDAP server (`opendldap-server`, `10.172.10.2`).
5. There is no special restrictive firewall rules:

[image: Firewall rules]

### Connectivity tests

1. I start a SSH session from the `openldap-server` at `10.172.10.2` to `exovie` at `172.24.0.20`.
2. My application `train-graphql` is connected to the `openldap-server` at `10.172.10.2` via the Serverless VPC Connector `euw6-connector` without issues.
3. A connectivity test on port 22 from the first instance of the Serverless VPC Connector `euw6-connector` at `10.94.0.2` to `exovie` at `172.24.0.20` is successful.

[image: GraphQL connectivity test]

### Final thoughts

Since I can SSH from Cloud Run to Compute Engine and from Compute Engine to `exovie`, a via solution could be to use a Compute ENgine VM as proxy to achieve this connection, but it sounds like a dirty hack.

Comment: Did you enable **Route all traffic through the VPC connector** for Cloud Run?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes I did.

Comment: VPC connectors are not transitive. You can go from `A -> B`  but not from `A -> B -> C`. Cloud VPN is supported provided that it is configured in `B` routing to `C`. I am not sure what you have configured from your question. A is Cloud Run, B is the VPC, C is on-prem.

Comment: @MathieuBour your issue has been resolved?